# Como insertar datos de una tabla a otra agarrando los datos con la superglobal GET

Tags: php, mysql, poo

Buenas tengo un problema , he creado un método que se llama `setUpCar()` este método lo hice para cuando pinche la carta que suba el producto a mi carrito, y quiero que los datos que obtenga el `$_GET` los capte el método y haga el query aquí un breve ejemplo del código `

```
public function setUpCar()
            {

                $conn = new Conection();
                $conn->CreateConnection();
                $id_pro=$_GET['id'];
                $name= $_GET['name'];
                $id=0;




                $query="INSERT INTO car (id_car, id_pro, name) VALUES 
                ((SELECT id_pro, name FROM products1 ) $id, $id_pro ,$name " ;
                $result = $conn->ExecuteQuery($query);

                if($result)
                {
                    $rowCount = $conn->GetCountAffectedRows($query);

                        print_r('<h1 class="display-4">The item is add</h1>');



                    }else{
                        echo '<div class="container">'.'<h1 class="display-1 text-center">Error</h1>'.'</div>';
                }
    return $result;`
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Así no te va a funcionar, tienes que obtener los datos del GET **fuera de la función** y luego llamar a la función pasándole los datos en parámetro. O sea, esto iría fuera de la función: `$id_pro=$_GET['id']; $name= $_GET['name'];`  Luego, llamas a la función: `setUpCar($id_pro,$name);` Por supuesto, debes cambiar la signatura de la función, agregando los parámetros: `public function setUpCar($id_pro,$name) {$conn = new Conection(); $conn->CreateConnection(); $id=0; $query="INSERT INTO ... //resto del código }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que la función *funcione* hay que llamarla:

```
setUpCar();
```

Aunque conviene siempre evaluar los datos que vienen en métodos como GET, POST, etc. Esos datos se pueden evaluar usando un operador ternario combinado con `empty`. Luego se verifica el estado de las variables, pasándolas a la función si tienen datos o emitiendo un mensaje de error en caso de que los datos vengan vacíos.

Sería esto más o menos:

#### Fuera de la función

```
$id_pro=( empty($_GET['id'])   ) ? NULL : $_GET['id'];
$name=  ( empty($_GET['name']) ) ? NULL : $_GET['name'];

if ($id_pro && $name){
    setUpCar($id_pro,$name);
} else {
    echo "Error: Hay datos vacíos en GET";
}
```

#### Función, recibiendo desde fuera los parámetros con los que va a trabajar

```
public function setUpCar($id_pro, $name)
            {

                $conn = new Conection();
                $conn->CreateConnection();
                $id=0;

                $query="INSERT INTO car (id_car, id_pro, name) VALUES 
                ((SELECT id_pro, name FROM products1 ) $id, $id_pro ,$name " ;
                $result = $conn->ExecuteQuery($query);

                if($result)
                {
                    $rowCount = $conn->GetCountAffectedRows($query);
                        print_r('<h1 class="display-4">The item is add</h1>');
                    }else{
                        echo '<div class="container">'.'<h1 class="display-1 text-center">Error</h1>'.'</div>';
                }
    return $result;

    /*resto del código*/
```

---

> **Nota sobre la seguridad**:
>
> Una consulta ejecutada así: `(SELECT id_pro, name FROM products1 )
>   $id, $id_pro ,$name` podría ser vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL.
>   Deberías implementar consultas preparadas si no lo estás haciendo.
>   Aquí no se puede ver con claridad, puesto que tu código es enviado a
>   una función propia llamada `ExecuteQuery`.

Comment: el ExecuteQuery es un metodo que cree en una Clase llamada Conection.php, este metodo ejecuta las querys mandadas de parametro, y usa de antemano la funcion query(), para ejecutar

Comment: En pocas palabras, el código no está protegido contra inyección SQL @EmmanuelOrtega. Recomiendo que leas sobre el tema para que blindes los métodos de tu clase contra posibles ataques de este tipo, los cuales pueden ser muy graves: desde borrar todos los datos de la tabla hasta tomar control del sistema en algunos caso, ya que a través de una consulta SQL se puede escribir en archivos si el usuario que se usa para la conexión tuviese privilegios para ello.

Comment: ok ok , muchas gracias!